# Error connecting to Salesforce in C#

Tags: c#, salesforce

I am getting exception in connecting to Professional edition of Salesforce. I tried in developer Salesforce and it successfully connects. I am using REST for both. I am a beginner in Salesforce and do not have any idea about what is causing this error.

Here's my code:

```
public static async Task ConnectSalesforce()
        {
            //create auth client to retrieve token
            var auth = new AuthenticationClient();

            //get back URL and token
            await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync("ConsumerId", "Consumersecret", "username", "password"+"security token", "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");

            var forceClient = new ForceClient(auth.InstanceUrl, auth.AccessToken, auth.ApiVersion);
            Console.Write("Connected to Salesforce.");
        }
    }
```

Here's the exception: "Retry your request"

[image]

Comment: @Suren Srapyan, Thank you for editing but can you suggest some solution for this problem ?

Comment: You may be hitting a TLS 1.0 issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647591/error-with-salesforce-authentication-from-c-sharp-clients

Comment: @superfell, Thank you.