# Getting "Bad Request" error for POST request to salesforce API

Tags: c#, post, salesforce, http-status-code-400

I am trying to send a POST request to salesforce api in C# but I am getting Bad Request error 400.

> Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException'
>   occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");

var postData = "grant_type=password";
postData += "&client_id=A73MVG9qBb0Fl2vjGhrbZAN2hk9zfTsODFzWH";
postData += "&client_secret=35027716280633505312";
postData += "&username=amir@gmail.com";
postData += "&password=1234567890Fu0qqKrUodRcpMLuHrviyqX3u";

var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
      stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I sent my POST request with Postman, it works. but generated code with Postman for C# returns the same error.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "082809c3-f3f4-14f1-81f7-d6832618f905");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=password&client_id=A73MVG9qBb0Fl2vjGhrbZAN2hk9zfTsODFzWH&client_secret=35027716280633505312&username=amir%40gmail.com&password=1234567890Fu0qqKrUodRcpMLuHrviyqX3u", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: What's the body of the HTTP response?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to get a bearer token from salesforce oauth api endpoint, care to show us the response? That helps to figure out the problem.

Comment: It occurs an unhandled exception and response body is null. 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll  

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get a bearer token from salesforce oauth api endpoint.

Comment: I used Postman to get token, it works. But generated code with Postman doesn't work in C# and returns the same error.

Comment: catch the exception and read the response body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with SalesForce authentication from C# Client(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647591/error-with-salesforce-authentication-from-c-sharp-clients)

Comment: I think you are not sending the actual password concatenating with the security token.

You must append the user’s security token to their password A security token is an automatically-generated key from Salesforce. For example, if a user's password is mypassword, and their security token is XXXXXXXXXX, then the value provided for this parmeter must be mypasswordXXXXXXXXXX. For more information on security tokens see “Reset Your Security Token” in the online help.

Comment: @superfell, Yes, thank you. It solved my problem.