# Error connecting to Salesforce through force.com C#

Tags: c#, oauth, salesforce, force.com

I am using the Force.com Toolkit for .NET and trying to connect to Salesforce. See my code below.

```
var instance = "test101";
var testMode = !instance.ToUpper().Equals("LIVE");

using (var auth = new AuthenticationClient())
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(_consumerKey, 
                _consumerSecret,
                _salesforceUser + (testMode ? "." + instance : ""), 
                _salesforcePass,
                $"http://{(testMode ? "test" : "login")}.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"
            ).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // error here

    _client = new ForceClient(auth.InstanceUrl, auth.AccessToken, "v30.0");
}
```

When this executes I get the following error (where indicated):

`Salesforce.Common.ForceAuthException: 'grant type not supported'`

There are lots of links suggesting that a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` would fix this but there is no way to specify this using this method.

I have reviewed this link [Error with SalesForce authentication from C# Client(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647591/error-with-salesforce-authentication-from-c-sharp-clients) but it is using an HttpClient and not the authentication client as per the documentation (https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET).

Has anybody got this working?

Comment: Did you ever solve this one?

Comment: No i switched to the salesforcesharp library from nuget which works well.